# How to dynamically insert unknown number of variables from a list (or array) into a method argument, in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

Example:

```
public class Example {
  public int doMath(String name, int... a) {
    System.out.println("My name is " + name);
    for (int i: a)
      int b = a+a
    return (b);
  }
  public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] testArray = new int[]{1,2,3}; //In this case size of the array is 3.
                                        // Could be any number during runtime.
    
    doMath(test[0],test[1],test[2]); //Need to insert values from into the doMath argument,
                                     // dynamically because
                                     // will not know length of array
                                     // during compile time
  }
}
```

I have list/array containing objects, and the method that I will be inserting these values into contain a vararg argument. I need to dynamically insert these values into this method, without hard coding the size of the list. Because during runtime the user inputs, can vary from anywhere between 0 - 100. And I need to be able to insert the values from this list into this method, into their proper position.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some problems ...

1. You can not call non static methods from static methods.
2. You can not declare a local variable(inside the loop) and return it outside the scope. Its compile time error.
3. You do not need varargs when you will work with just arrays. You need varargs when you might have an array of element, or a single element.

```java
public class Example {

    // the main method can call this method
    public static int doMath(String name, int[] a) {
        System.out.println("My name is " + name);
        int b = 0;
        for (int i : a)
            b = b + i;
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        while (condition) { // just for example with a dynamic array.
            int size = 10; // you might ask user for the size of the array

            int[] array = new int[size];
            for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
                array[index] = index * 2; // you might ask user for input
            int result = doMath("math", array);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, i'm dealing with a predefined function, in fact it is a jdbc template, in which the function actually cares about the position and number of elements, because it is trying to match the array element value with the mysql prepared statements. What I gave above was just an example. Therefore please try to answer the question, in which how to dynamically insert the elements value into a method's parameter section.

Comment: @spider1919 well, use an array, this is insert parameters dynamically! You can have N number of positions in the array, just iterate over it. What are you trying to do (arg1, arg2, arg3) then (arg1, arg2) then (arg1) is possible only at compile time using varargs, not possible at runtime.